# Removing items from a list with LINQ (removeAll)

Tags: c#, linq-to-entities

I have two lists of objects, and I have been learning how to remove items from one list if they appear in another.

I have come up with this:

```
result.ResultantPoliciesTable.RemoveAll(item => result.PoliciesTable.Select
(f => f.PolicyName).Contains(item.PolicyName));
```

This works, but if an integer property of the object in `ResultantPoliciesTable` called `ManagementID` equals a value I will supply then I do not want this object to be removed.

Can anyone help me extend this query to achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the following:

```
int doNotRemoveID = 7862384732;
result.ResultantPoliciesTable.RemoveAll(
    item => item.ManagementID != doNotRemoveID && 
            result.PoliciesTable.Select(f => f.PolicyName).Contains(item.PolicyName));
```

The variable `item` will be filled with each record from your `ResultantPoliciesTable`, and if your resulting method returns `true`, it will be removed. Thus, adding a check to see if `item.ManagementID` needs to be excluded should be enough to fit your needs.

Comment: No results are removed now

Comment: Then either all properties have your excluded `ManagementID`, or their `PolicyName` does *not* exist in `result.PoliciesTable`.

Comment: Oops sorry I was running an old build so getting strange results. Thankyou for your help this works great

Answer (score 0):

```
result.ResultantPoliciesTable
      .RemoveAll(item => 
                      result.PoliciesTable
                            .Where(i => i.ManagementID!=myId)
                            .Select(f => f.PolicyName)
                            .Contains(item.PolicyName)
                );
```